# average number of words and characters per comments in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the average number of words and characters of comments column adding 2 columns to [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qNeYRFJWVXl1BUjE3pfGIg8XLbBiqIuU) dataset. I tried this code but it just calculates the whole dataset without specifying for every row.

```
with open('diabetes-public-review-comment','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(sum(len(line) for line in lines)/len(lines))
```

Comment: try `readline()` and not `readlines()` this should read a single line at a time.

Comment: Probably best to treat this as a csv rather than a text file. Are you willing to use pandas? Otherwise use the csv module.

Comment: @ElyFialkoff I think `readlines()` is correct here, though it wouldn't be needed.  Simply using `for line in f` would be more efficient and avoid storing the whole file in memory at once.

Comment: As far as I can tell, each row in your dataset contains only a single comment, so by "average" you mean the average over all rows?  If so, there is only a single average number of words or characters for the whole dataset, and it doesn't seem to make sense to add this average to every single row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a 3rd party library you can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). A similar idea, verbose but memory-efficient, can be applied in regular Python with the `csv` module and `len` / `str.split`.

```
x = '''Comment
Table 5.2.3 (SMPG Plots results metadata): the Result Identifier should not be null. 
"such as": so there are other uses. It is recognized that the FDA currently does not accept files in Dataset-XML format (but they should). However, Dataset-XML is even not mentioned in the document - it should. Many of the "rules" (such as "maximum 40 characters") are based on the limitations of SAS Transport 5 that do not apply to Dataset-XML. A comment on this in the text where such rules are mentioned would be appropriate.
All "Type" columns in the model refer to SAS-XPT. It would be much better if the "define-XML" datatypes are listed, e.g. "integer" for --DY, "date/datetime" for --DTC, "text" for --ORRES, etc..
Space needed in middle of classifyinghypoglycemia'''

import pandas as pd

# replace StringIO(x) with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), delimiter='|')  # use an arbirary delimiter not used in file

# calculate and assign new columns
df['Characters'] = df['Comment'].str.len()
df['Words'] = df['Comment'].str.split().str.len()

# export to CSV
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)

print(df)

#                                              Comment  Characters  Words
# 0  Table 5.2.3 (SMPG Plots results metadata): the...          85     13
# 1  such as: so there are other uses. It is recogn...         427     75
# 2  All "Type" columns in the model refer to SAS-X...         193     31
# 3  Space needed in middle of classifyinghypoglycemia          49      6
```

Then calculate averages via:

```
mean_characters = df['Characters'].mean()
mean_words = df['Words'].mean()
```